# mTLS origination for egress traffic to wildcard arbitrary hosts

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

Is it possible with istio to make mTLS origination for egress traffic to wildcard arbitrary hosts with the following restrictions:

1. The application pods have to make simple HTTP requests, not HTTPS.
2. The mTLS origination should happen at the egress gateway.
3. Custom client and CA certificates have to be used.

Basically this scenario differs from the example in the official documentation [Egress using wildcard arbitrary hosts with SNI proxy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#setup-egress-gateway-with-sni-proxy) with the following things:

1. The application pod is using HTTP instead of HTTPS: `curl http:\\host1.example.com`. So the mTLS origination should happen at the egress gateway, not at the application pod.
2. Custom client and CA certificates are used.

I tried the desired scenario, but there is a problem that when the egress gateway routes the traffic to the SNI nginx proxy (`sni-proxy`), it can’t extract the hostname from the SNI TLS header. The error is: `*18 no host in upstream ":443"`. SNI is not set by the application pod (`sleep`), because it’s using simple HTTP, instead of HTTPS as in the official example. When the SNI is not set, the SNI proxy can't forward the traffic to specific host.

Is it possible in this scenario to configure istio egress gateway to originate mTLS to specific host using only wildcard hostname in the resources like `ServiceEntry`, `DestinationRule`, `VirtualService`, etc? For example: application pod to pass HTTP request header parameter, like `Host`, which to be used by the egress gateway to originate mTLS and set SNI header, which then will be used by the SNI proxy to forward the traffic to the specific host? In this case the egress gateway will originate mTLS traffic to specific host dynamically based on the HTTP request header?

Comment: Which version of Istio did you use?

Comment: Currently i am using Istio version 1.9.2

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that pod will send http requests, which are to be redirected to https via the gateway?

Comment: Yes @MikołajGłodziak. I want to understand is it possible the egress gateway to redirect to https, i.e. make mTLS origination?

Comment: Did you see [this page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#egress-gateway-for-http-traffic)? It is about egress gateway for http traffic.

Comment: Yes, i saw it. But it is related to specific hostnames, i.e. fully qualified domain names. I want to use wildcard domain names as described [in this page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/), but with TLS origination at the egress not at the application pod.

Comment: If I good understand your problem, [this section](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#setup-egress-gateway-with-sni-proxy) should be helpful.

Comment: It is helpful, but HTTPS is used in it. You can see in step 4 [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#configure-traffic-through-egress-gateway-with-sni-proxy) that they are using HTTPS `$ kubectl exec "$SOURCE_POD" -c sleep -- sh -c 'curl -s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"; curl -s https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"'`. I want to use HTTP (without TLS).

Comment: I'm wondering is it possible HTTP traffic (without TLS) to be routed from application container, through sidecar, then to egress gateway, where mTLS communication to be originated (using client certificates), then routed to SNI proxy and out? Using wildcard hosts.

Comment: I found one more [potential solution](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#configure-mutual-tls-origination-for-egress-traffic). In this case you can define a VirtualService to direct the traffic through the egress gateway from port 80 to 443.

Comment: Specific hostname `my-nginx.mesh-external.svc.cluster.local` is used not a wildcard one like `*.mesh-external.svc.cluster.local`. Please see the `host`, `hosts` and `sni` fields in the configurations.

Comment: Yes, I mean, does the effect you intend to get differs only from using wildcards in this setup?

Comment: Yes, the effect differs only from using wildcards. The problem with the [proposed potential solution](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#configure-mutual-tls-origination-for-egress-traffic) is that it uses specific host for the `sni` value in the `DestinationRule`s. The other values for the `host` and `hosts` params can be replaced with wildcard hostname.

Comment: Did you see [this page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#wildcard-configuration-for-a-single-hosting-server)? It is possible to use field `sniHosts` with the wildcard.